# How to check output from command - PERL

Tags: perl, output, stdout

i have a problem, I am new in Perl, so.
I want to get output from command i send to check if its done, for example:

In my module i run command my_zip_command file a_lot_of_file' and i want to my module wait until the massage 'all file were zip correctly' will be printed.

I tried get the STDOUT but it didnt work for me, or i just doing it wrong.

```
bash>my_zip_command file a_lot_of_file
>ziping file1 100%
>ziping file2 100%
>ziping file3 100%
>all file were zip correctly
bash>
```

Thanks for all your help

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to

1. Run a command from your perl script and
2. Capture the output of that command inside your perl script

this is the simplest way I can think of.

```
my @output = `my_zip_command file a_lot_of_file`;
```

`@output` will hold the complete output of the command.

Comment: also check ``$?`` for a zero exit code